# Data was not retrieved, the map says I can't go back

Tags: reactjs

The API gives me an error when I try to print the data on the screen, but when I check the console, it made two requests and returned an empty object in the first request, but I got my data in the second request. I received the error below when I returned with map.

```
import React,{useState,useEffect} from "react";
import Homepage from "../components/pages/homePage";
import Entry from "../components/entry/entry"
import axios from "axios"
import Cookies from "universal-cookie"

export default function Home() {
 const [post, setPost] = useState({});
    const cookie = new Cookies()
    const token = cookie.get("acsess_token")

    const getAll = async() => {
        const entry = await axios.get("/api/entry/entry", {
            headers: {
                "Authorization": token
            }
        })
            .then((response) => {
                return response.data
            })
            .then((rs) => setPost(rs))
            .catch((err) => { console.log(err) })
    }

 useEffect(() => {getAll()},[])

  return (
    <div className="flex  bg-home w-full">
      <Homepage />
      <div className="w-auto h-auto absolute left-48 m-1">

        {
          post.map((res) => {
           <p>{res}</p>
          })
        }
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Error code

```
 Line 31:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of issues here:

1. You are using `await` and `.then` + response.data is not an async function so chaining it with `.then` is wrong.

Instead:

```
const getAll = async() => {
    const entry = await axios.get("/api/entry/entry", {
         headers: {
             "Authorization": token
         }
    })
    setPost(entry.data)
}
```

2. You are not returning from `.map` function in JSX.

Instead, do:

```
{
  post.map((res) => {
    return <p>{res}</p>
  })
}
```

*or an implicit return like:*

```
{
  post.map(res => (
    <p> {res} </p>
  ))
}
```

Comment: I tried as you said, it worked, thanks

Answer (score 1):

add `return` before the paragraph tag and check or `return` the `map` function